# Algebraic topology question

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity

Let $f:S^2 \rightarrow S^2$ be continuous map such that $f(x) \neq f(-x)$ $\forall x \in S^2$. Prove that $f$ is surjective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f$ is *not* surjective. Then there is some point on the sphere it doesn't hit. By way of stereographic projection from that point, $f$ induces a function $f':S^2 \to \Bbb R^2$. By the [Borsuk-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem), ther must be an $x\in S^2$ such that $f'(x) = f'(-x)$. Passing back to $f$, we get that $f(x) = f(-x)$.

Comment: Now I remember the name of the theorem. :)

Comment: I am unable to understand how to get the map $f^{'}:S^2\to \Bbb R^2$;Will it be possible for you to explain that in some detail

Comment: @learnmore $S^2\setminus \{p\}$, for any single point $\{p\}\in S^2$, is diffeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$ (via stereographic projection). Call the diffeomorphism $\psi$. Then $f'=\psi\circ f:S^2\to \Bbb R^2$ is the map Arthur talks about.

Comment: Okay I got it ,Thank you very much@Danu

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is not surjective, then by taking away a point which is not in the image, we get a continuous map $g:S^2\to S^2-pt$. Since $S^2-pt$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$, we can conclude using  Theorem 1.10 in Hatcher, which says:

Every continuous map $F$ from $S^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a point $x$ in the domain so that $F(x)=F(-x)$.